# How to query for available item?

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if anyone could help me with querying availability on my mysql db.

sooo, i have a two tables: tbl_items(unit items), and tbl_reservations.

**tbl_reservations

-barcode

-dateReserved

-timeStart

-timeEnd**

**tbl_items

-barcode

-itemName

-itemDesc**

What i wanted to do is something like this(please refer to the image):
[image: Reservations]

so far, this is my query:

```
SELECT a.bcode, b.resdate, b.timestart, b.timeend
FROM tbl_items a
INNER JOIN tbl_reservations b
on a.bcode=b.bcode
WHERE a.bcode
not in
(
  Select bcode
  FROM tbl_reservations
  WHERE bcode not in
  (
  SELECT bcode
  FROM tbl_reservations
  where resdate='2013-09-25' AND retdate is null
  )
AND ((timestart < '10:00'AND timeend < '10:00')
AND (timestart > '15:00' AND timeend > '15:00'))
)
```

but even with this long a code, it still allows some equipment that are already booked or should be unavailable to show up.

any help?

Thanks! :D

Screenshot of resultset with the reservations that i mean NOT to be included in the resultset:
[image: Resultset]

The highlighted ones are the ones that overlap the conditions in the code above...

Update: here's the new code... I was surprised because it returned the rows that has both timestart and timeend before 10:00.

```
select rsv.controlno, rsv.bcode, rsv.resdate, rsv.timestart, rsv.timeend
FROM
(
  select bcode
  from tbl_items
) i
inner join tbl_reservations rsv
on i.bcode=rsv.bcode
WHERE resdate='2013-09-25' AND NOT (rsv.timeend > '10:00' AND rsv.timestart < '15:00');
```

Comment: "it still allows some equipment that are already booked or should be unavailable to show up." - can you give some examples of this so we can help debug? As a first step you might want to put extra brackets around the `AND ( (...) OR (...) )` part so it's definitely got the correct precedence.

Comment: Result set and updated code... @Rup..

Comment: Try this link: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. I believe switching an AND for an OR will do the trick.  The outside AND requires that one of the conditions is true.  The inside OR will grab reservations before the period, OR outside the period, but none inside the period.

```
SELECT a.bcode, b.resdate, b.timestart, b.timeend
FROM tbl_items a
INNER JOIN tbl_reservations b
on a.bcode=b.bcode
WHERE a.bcode
not in
(
  Select bcode
  FROM tbl_reservations
  WHERE bcode not in
  (
  SELECT bcode
  FROM tbl_reservations
  where resdate='2013-09-25' AND retdate is null
  )
AND 
    ((timestart < '10:00' AND timeend < '10:00')
    OR (timestart > '15:00' AND timeend > '15:00')

    )
)
```

Switch out the AND for an OR for the range of times.

Comment: thanks for the reply, actually, i cant allow the kind that spans the whole time range but does not start or end inside...

Comment: Great, I'll remove the 'span' option.  Does the OR meet your needs?

Comment: the OR still not filtering enough... still allows overlapping ones... thanks for the reply, i've got a new code, it filters even better than my previous code. :D will post it.